# php post variables through JSON response

Tags: php, json

Does anyone has an Idea how to get the POST value send to the php file through the same php response wrapped with JSON?

What I did so far was to send username and password to server side authentication. But it triggers an error of field missing. So I want to check the received data at the server side at the console.

```
  if(isset($_POST['u_name']) && isset($_POST['u_pass'])){

       $username = $_POST['u_name'];
       $pass = $_POST['u_pass'];


  } else {
       // required field is missing
       $response["success"] = 0;
       $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing" + $_POST['u_name'] + $_POST['u_name']; // <--- this is my line 48
       // echoing JSON response
       echo json_encode($response);

  }
```

But I 'm getting an error  like this

```
   <br />
   <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: u_name in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\TestCordova\login_check.php</b> on line <b>48</b><br />
   <br />
   <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: u_name in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\TestCordova\login_check.php</b> on line <b>48</b><br />
   {"success":0,"message":0}
```

Comment: ... Well, you are quiet literally checking if the values are there, and if not, then throwing a error, why are you surprised that you get a error?

Comment: `else` is executing because `$_POST['u_name']` is not there. So how can you except the value

Comment: you cannot use $_POST['u_name'] in else because if it goes to else that mean $_POST['u_name'] isn't set

Comment: @epodax I'm not suprised. I just want to check what are those values I'm sending. Hope you got what I really want from this?

Comment: @ast-snail is there anyway I can check them?

Comment: Just use "Required field(s) is missing" OR "Username and Password fields missing". You can not use same variable in else condition of isset.

Comment: Do you understand what `isset()` does?

Comment: @riggsfolly It just check whether the $_POST() variable is set for a value....? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, so if `isset($_POST['u_name'])` returns false you cannot then use `$_POST['u_name']` in an error message in the ELSE! Apart from the obvious thing that you already know it does not have a value, **it does not actually exist**

Comment: @riggsfolly Got it.......

Comment: So as @RuchishParikh tried to say, just output a generalised error message saying `"Username and Password fields missing"`

Comment: **Side Note:** `isset()` can take more than one parameter so your IF can be coded as `if ( isset($_POST['u_name'], $_POST['u_pass']) ) {`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['u_name']) && isset($_POST['u_pass'])){
   $username = $_POST['u_name'];
   $pass = $_POST['u_pass'];
} else {
   // required field is missing
   $response["success"] = 0;
   $string = "";
   if(!isset($_POST['u_name'])
    $string = "User name";
   if(!isset($_POST['u_pass'])
    $string.= " Password";

   $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing ".$string ; // <--- this is my line 48
   // echoing JSON response
   echo json_encode($response);

}  
?>
```